# Cannot use constructor parameters with dependency injection in asp.net core test

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, integration-testing

I use the [WebHostBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilder?view=aspnetcore-5.0) class to configure a server for integration tests in asp.net core. While this is working like a charm I now ran into issues with services that have a constructor parameter along other dependencies. These services are registered in my startup with the following pattern:

```
        services.AddSingleton<MyInterface, MyClass>(x =>
            new MyClass(x.GetRequiredService<SomeInterfaceDependency>(),
                        x.GetRequiredService<AnotherInterfaceDependency>(),
                        someStringOrEnumOrWhateverParameter));
```

When I run the tests my requests that use this service fail and I do not even understand at what point the request fails. The diagnostic information that I get is limited to a one line stack trace:

```
    ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
```

So my question is: How can I work with services that have constructor parameters in integration tests? Any pointers in the right direction are very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be manually creating `WebHostBuilder`s, instead use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` package and its `TestServer` and `WebApplicationFactory` classes that do this all for you, as explained on MSDN:

https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#aspnet-core-integration-tests